# Adding ListItems with whitespace to a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I add items to a ListBox with text values such as "*_*_foo" etc? It seems to trim it automatically.

Comment: which technology are you using? web ? wfp? winform ? whitespace ?

Comment: whitespace technology (as used by nasa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;&nbsp;") + "foo", "foovalue"));
```

^^